# Error: attempted to import the Node standard library module "crypto". It failed

Tags: javascript, react-native, node-modules, expo, ethereum

I was going to use `ethereumjs-wallet`. But I decided to use `ethereumjs-wallet-react-native` because it's for the web. If you look at [the link](https://github.com/WoeOm/ethereumjs-wallet-react-native), it says `import` the two modules. So I took two modules and tried to `import` them, but there was a problem.

an error-causing code:

```js
import { asyncRandomBytes } from 'react-native-secure-randombytes'
import safeCrypto from 'react-native-safe-crypto'

window.randomBytes = asyncRandomBytes
window.scryptsy = safeCrypto.scrypt
```

Errormessage:

> Unable to resolve module "react-native-secure-randombytes"

I wanted to solve this problem, but I couldn't solve it, so I decided to take a detour.

Error Resolved Code:

```js
import safeCrypto from "react-native-fast-crypto";
const { RNRandomBytes } = NativeModules;

window.randomBytes = RNRandomBytes.randomBytes;
window.scryptsy = safeCrypto.scrypt;
```

This may cause problems later, but it's settled for now. However, there was another problem when we called up and executed `ethereumjs-wallet-react-native.`

errormessage:

> The package at "node_modules/ethereumjs-wallet-react-native/index.js"
>   attempted to import the Node standard library module "crypto". It
>   failed because React Native does not include the Node standard
>   library. Read more at
>   https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq/#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo

So I downloaded `crypto-browserify`, but it didn't work.

Code that attempted to resolve

```js
import safeCrypto from "react-native-fast-crypto";
const { RNRandomBytes } = NativeModules;
import Wallet from "ethereumjs-wallet-react-native";
var crypto = require("crypto-browserify");

window.randomBytes = RNRandomBytes.randomBytes;
window.scryptsy = safeCrypto.scrypt;
...
 async componentDidMount() {
    const wallet = await Wallet.generate();
  }
```

this is package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "ethereumjs-wallet-react-native": "^0.6.7",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "expokit": "32.1.1",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-fast-crypto": "^1.8.1",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
```

The code for "ethereumjs-wallet-react-native/index.js" is located on [the link](https://github.com/WoeOm/ethereumjs-wallet-react-native) in my article.

Please help us. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `but it didn't work` - in what way?

Comment: @Jaromanda X Error message is same error

Comment: so, you still get `attempted to import the Node standard library module "crypto"` - odd, since you aren't attempting that - oh, wait, of course you are, because it's `ethereumjs-wallet-react-native` that imports `crypto` - which it will always attempt to do, unless you change it so it doesn't

Comment: @Jaromanda X I just followed Github guide. What did you say i didn't try?

Comment: I didn't say you didn't try anything ... I said you haven't changed anything about what `ethereumjs-wallet-react-native` is importing

Comment: @Jaromanda X I think I misunderstood because I lacked English skills. So how do we fix it?

Comment: "But I decided to use ethereumjs-wallet-react-native because it's for the web." React Native is _not_ for the web.

Comment: @smarx  I mean that `ethereumjs-wallet` is for the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-native-randombytes` were Re-link.

and

I was used `import crypto from "crypto";`

Recreate Successful Code

```js
import crypto from "crypto";
import safeCrypto from "react-native-fast-crypto";
import { asyncRandomBytes } from "react-native-secure-randombytes";
...
window.randomBytes = asyncRandomBytes;
window.scryptsy = safeCrypto.scrypt;
```